# Writing a function that prints a pyramid - two parameters

Tags: python

I'm working on this problem, that reads as follows:

**Problem:** Write a function that draws a pyramid on your screen. The function needs two arguments. The first is the height of the pyramid. The second argument is optional: if not supplied, the symbol "#" should be used to draw the pyramid. Otherwise, if the users enters " * " for example, the pyramid should consist of asterisks.

**Attempt:** I wrote this program:

```
def main():
    h = int(input("Please enter the height of the pyramid: "))
    symbol = str(input("Enter the desired symbol or press enter for standard (#): "))


def pyramid(h,symbol):
    if symbol == "" or symbol == "#":
        for i in range(h):
            pyr = print(" " * (h-i - 1) + "#" * (2 * i + 1))

        return pyr


    else:
        for i in range(h):
            pyr = print(" " * (h-i - 1) + symbol * (2 * i + 1))

        return pyr

    print()

main()
```

But this is not working properly when I try to call this. Can someone point out my mistakes? Also, I'm not sure how to deal with the 'optional' property of the function. Should I stick to my approach or is there a better way to define that ?

Comment: How do you know it's not working properly?

Comment: `pyr = print` Here is a problem. THis makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your logic is fine, you can try

```
def pyramid(h,symbol):
    if symbol == "" or symbol == "#":
        for i in range(h):
            print(" " * (h-i - 1) + "#" * (2 * i + 1))
    else:
        for i in range(h):
            print(" " * (h-i - 1) + symbol * (2 * i + 1))
    print()

pyramid(5, "#")
```

```
    #
   ###
  #####
 #######
#########
```

your problems:

- `pyr = print(" " * (h-i - 1) + "#" * (2 * i + 1))` .... `print` function return `None`, then `pyr` store `None`
- `return pyr` statement return `pyr` variable content and finish `pyramid` function
- `pyramid` function isn't calling never

**Improving code**

you can remove unnecessary if,

```
def pyramid(h,symbol="#"):
    for i in range(h):
        print(" " * (h-i - 1) + symbol * (2 * i + 1))
    print()

pyramid(5)
```

you can return a str

```
def pyramid(h,symbol="#"):
    out = ""
    for i in range(h):
        out += (" " * (h-i - 1)) + (symbol * (2 * i + 1)) + "\n"
    return out

print(pyramid(5))
```

or, online solution

```
def pyramid(h,symbol="#"):
    return "\n".join((" " * (h-i - 1)) + (symbol * (2 * i + 1)) for i in range(h))

print(pyramid(5))
```

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing out my mistakes. But if I enter pyramid(5, ) , i.e. with no second argument provided, it gives me an error. Is there some way to make it print the pyramid with the symbol #, even if we haven't provided a second argument, or is that not possible at all? I think that is what the problem is asking of us.

Comment: you can try:  `pyramid(5, "#")` or `pyramid(5)` or `pyramid(5, "@")`